# Weird characters when trying to grab char * from fstream

Tags: c++, string, fstream, null-terminated

I am trying to read 4 characters at a specific position from a file. The code is simple but the result is really confusing:

```
fstream dicomFile;
dicomFile.open(argv[1]);
dicomFile.seekg(128,ios::beg);
char * memblock = new char [4];
dicomFile.read(memblock,4); 
cout<<"header is "<<memblock<<endl;
```

Ideally the result should be "DICM" but the actual result from the console was "DICM" plus weird characters, as shown in the picture. What's more, every time I run it, the characters are different. I suppose this may be something about ASCII and Unicode, I tried to change project property from Unicode to multibytes and then change back, no difference.

[image]

Does anyone know what's happening here and how do I solve it please? Thanks very much!

Comment: I'll take "What is a null-terminated string" for $200 Alex.

Answer (score 3):

C style (`char *`) strings use the concept of [null-terminators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string). This means strings are ended with a `'\0'` character in their last element. You are reading in exactly 4 characters into a 4 character buffer, which does not include a null character to end the string. C and C++ will happily run right off the end of your buffer in search for the null terminator that signifies the end of the string.

Quick fix is to create a block of `length + 1`, read in `length` data, then set `str[length] = '\0'`. In your case it would be as below.

```
char * memBlock = new char [5];
// populate memBlock with 4 characters
memBlock[ 4 ] = '\0';
```

A better solution is to use `std::string` instead of `char *` when working with strings in C++.

Comment: I'd think "C++ strings" are spelled `std::string` and they do _not_ use the concept of null-terminted strings...

Comment: I meant 'char *' as a string in C/C++, but yes std::string should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You could also initialize the buffer with zeros, putting null-terminators at every location.

```
char * memblock = new char [5](); // zeros, and one element longer
```

Fairly inefficient though.